# missing 1 required positional argument: Cant find how the arguments are working flask/sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In my flask app , i created a function to add a new admin and show it in table.
But am unable to add as it shows error that it **require 1 positional argument**  when i i**nput 5 arguments** , but when i enter **6 arguments** it **gives a different error** which i cannot find on internet.

```
>>> from web.adminMethod import *
>>> addRestadmin("id","name","mail","mobile","address","password") 
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "D:\projects\websites\foodWeb\web\adminMethod.py", line 23, in addRestadmin 
     rest=Restadmin(id,name,mail,mobile,address,password)
     TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 7 were given
>>> addRestadmin("name","mail","mobile","address","password")
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     TypeError: addRestadmin() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password'       
>>>  addRestadmin(rname=name,rmail=mail,rmobile=mobile,raddress=address,rpassword=password)
     TypeError: addRestadmin() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rname'
```

addRestadmin() function :

```
def addRestadmin(id,name,mail,mobile,address,password):
    rest=Restadmin(id,name,mail,mobile,address,password)
    db.session.add(cust)
    db.session.commit
```

Restadmin database structure :

```
class Restadmin(db.Model):
    rid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    rname = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    rmail = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    rmobile = db.Column(db.Integer,unique=True, nullable=False)
    raddress = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    rpassword = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addRestadmin function should look like this:

```
def addRestadmin(id,name,mail,mobile,address,password):
    rest=Restadmin(rid=id, rname=name, rmail=mail,rmobile=mobile,raddress=address,rpassword=password)
    db.session.add(rest)
    db.session.commit
```

and call it like this:

```
addRestadmin("name","mail","mobile","address","password")
```

Comment: Now my code is working . There were 2 major problems , 1st i didnt use () after commit , and then i was calling id uselessly as i set it to autoincrement. Your code helped it making it clear how it should properly be. Thanks for that.